# Connecting Logitech M720 mouse with Bluetooth (Linux and Windows)

Tags: linux, windows-10, bluetooth, logitech-mouse

Got me a nice new shiny M720 mouse. It work on Linux and W10 using the Unifying dongle, but I would prefer to use it with Bluetooth.

On a recent HP 15.6" Elitebook on Windows 10, I can make the mouse appear when Windows scans for available devices, but if I click on it the connection fails.

On a Lenovo P51 with Kubuntu 16.04, it can appear in the list of BT devices (while not showing up at the same time in the output of `hcitool scan`), but the connection fails (but it is still marked as "connected" afterwards). It then shows up in the device list with a mouse icon, but its type is "Unknown" and it doesn't work as a mouse.

On a Lenovo P53 with Kubuntu 19.10, it doesn't even show up in the list of BT devices (I can connect to other BT devices).

I have seen a few answers here and there recommending to install `blueman` on Linux, but as far as I can tell BlueMan doesn't do anything more than the BT manager of the KDE desktop.

Any idea what to try next? Did my initial failed attempts use up all the channels? Is this mouse doomed?

Edit: additional infos:

```
>hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB                                                                      
        BD Address: 28:16:AD:10:96:94  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6                               
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN                                                                      
        RX bytes:18641 acl:64 sco:0 events:2627 errors:0                                            
        TX bytes:608848 acl:64 sco:0 commands:2536 errors:0                                         
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87                                           
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
        Name: 'Xenoid'
        Class: 0x1c010c
        Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
        Device Class: Computer, Laptop
        HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0x100
        LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x100
        Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

The mouse eventually shows up in the scans (but this took several tries)

```
>hcitool lescan
LE Scan ...
DD:BB:69:22:FE:65 M720 Triathlon
DD:BB:69:22:FE:65 (unknown)
C0:28:8D:FD:84:BC 
C0:97:27:56:74:7B (unknown)
4B:06:DE:B6:46:97 (unknown)
4B:06:DE:B6:46:97 (unknown)
D4:6A:6A:16:49:66 (unknown)
7B:A3:F8:B1:AB:75 (unknown)
74:38:B7:A2:ED:CD (unknown)
4A:6F:54:C8:9D:4B (unknown)
C0:28:8D:FD:84:BC (unknown)
58:C3:34:AB:1E:08 (unknown)
```

(however the scan never terminates... I have to Ctrl-C out of it)

`hcitool leinfo` doesn't seem to work:

```
>hcitool leinfo DD:BB:69:22:FE:65
Requesting information ...
Could not create connection: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Start with the Windows 10 machine. Remove the Unifying USB device, restart the computer, then in Devices and Printers select Add Device.  There should be a button (probably on the bottom of the Mouse) to connect to Bluetooth. Does this work?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using the dongle?

Comment: @John The 720 is "special", it can connect to several devices so there is combined device select/pair.

Comment: @Moab Because the dongle of my previous just broke off in the USB socket and since I carry the computer a lot, I don't want to have to insert/remove the dongle each time.

Comment: Can you just use only Bluetooth? My LogiTech mouse is just Bluetooth. Disable the USB port.

Comment: @john Of course I tried without putting the dongle in the computer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It eventually worked, after I removed all dongles in the vicinity. It also seems that the Device 1 is always the dongle. So to try the BT association you have to select device 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

The Logitech M720 is labeled as Bluetooth Smart which is a.k.a Bluetooth Low Energy, BLE, or Bluetooth 4.0 (or newer). `hcitool scan` will only show classic bluetooth. The proper command is `hcitool lescan`.

Here is a link for a gotcha about `lescan` feature. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062037/hcitool-lescan-shows-i-o-error

To check version of Bluetooth supported in Ubuntu, use the command `hciconfig -a`. Only one hci0 device should be present. The HCI Version will need to be 4.0 or newer.

```bash
$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 5C:80:B6:58:52:D6  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
        UP RUNNING PSCAN INQUIRY
        RX bytes:128087 acl:4994 sco:0 events:3962 errors:0
        TX bytes:743983 acl:73 sco:0 commands:3553 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
        Name: 'Ubuntu-1804-Laptop'
        Class: 0x1c010c
        Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
        Device Class: Computer, Laptop
        HCI Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Revision: 0x100
        LMP Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Subversion: 0x100
        Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Please see edited answer.